# Chumper Datatable in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

I am trying to make use of chumper in laravel 5 but have encountered the following problem

**FatalErrorException in HomeController.php line 11:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Datatable' not found**

I have installed the develop branch via composer and updated providers and aliases as per the instructions any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you need to declare `use Datatable;` in your controller. Because Laravel 5's Controllers used Namespace(This is different from Laravel 4).

Answer (score 0):

this seems like composer issue,

```
$ composer dump-autoload -o
```

And you should be good to go.